# No lrtest() function available in lmtest

Tags: r

I have got a strange problem with using functions which are supposed to be in the libraries lmtest & language R (downloaded from cran.r-project recently), namely lrtest() and pvals.fnc() - however, they are not available. I have upgraded my R-version to 2.12.2 but it has not solved the problem.

```
library(lmtest)
lrtest()
returns: Error: could not find function "lrtest"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
T

Comment: Works for me on win 7 x 64. Maybe you can provide the output of `sessionInfo()` ?

Answer (score 4):

post your `sessionInfo()`.

`lmtest:::lrtest(x)` should call a generic function which then determines the appropriate code to run on 'x'.

If you have not updated your packages, you may perhaps need to do so, or simply re-run `install.packages('lmtest')` for your updated R install.